# Calculating Statistics of attribute field to use it in another calculation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, attribute-table, python-parser

I want the statistics of an attribute field to use in another calculation, i can view the statistics using the field properties menu
[image]

I want these to normalised the data of field 'Ia' using the following formula,

Is=(Ia-min(Ia))/(max(Ia)-min(Ia))

I have tried the following expression

[image]
How to perform this calculation using python parser

`OID  Ia    Normalised
1     23        1.00
2     12        0.00
3     17        0.45`

Comment: Take a look at the Summary Statistics tool to perhaps calculate the statistics you need in a separate table first and then process the table and feature class using an arcpy search cursor and an update cursor.

Comment: What happened when you tried that expression?

Comment: If you use the pre logic code block you can create a searchCursor to iterate through the Ia field and append all values to this list. You will then be able to run max() and min() on the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with some clever use of arcpy, static variables and numpy. In my example I've created a dummy equation so you can see how it is done, obvious you would need to alter it to your dataset as I do not have that.

So below is the field calculator note python, code block and I'm calling a function called `calc()` passing in a field called Year.

[image: Set up calculator]

The entire code in the code block is:

```py
import arcpy
import numpy

# Initialize mx and mn
mx = -1
mn = -1

def calc(yr):
  # Declare as global
  global mx
  global mn

  # If mx is -1 then extract out min and max, we need only do this once
  # Note code is explicitly naming a layer loaded in ArcMap and I am
  # extracting min/max from ES90POP field 
  if mx == -1:
    np = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray("fcBangladesh_GRUMPv1",["ES90POP"])
    mx= np["ES90POP"].max()
    mn = np["ES90POP"].min()

  # Compute equation and return
  # This is a meaningless equation it simply shows you 
  # how to use the extracted min/max with a field (Year) passed in
  x = ( yr * mn) / mx
  return  x
```

This code assumes a starting value of -1 for min or max is not a number within your data range.

Comment: +1 This is cool. I didn't realize quite how the pre-logic script worked, but now it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to get the max of one float value in one row, rather than the max of all.

You need to be searching a list for the max and min. You can do this by creating a list and appending all values to it.

If you add to the pre-logic code block:

```
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor("table_name","Ia")
valuelist = []
for row in cursor:
    valuelist.append(row[0])
```

then you can use:

```
(!Ia!-min(valuelist))/(max(valuelist)-min(valuelist))
```

Answer (score 0):

While others are suggesting making this calculation in field calculator, this seems quite inefficient to me, as it means the min and max values will need to be determined with each row. I suggest using the python window instead.

[image: Python Window]

Define a function that finds all the check field's values, finds the min and the max, and then updates the update field accordingly.

```
def Calculation (layer, checkFld, updateFld):

    #get all values
    checkVals = [val for val
                 in arcpy.da.SearchCursor
                 (layer, checkFld)
                 if val != None]

    #get mins and maxs
    minVal = min (checkVals)
    maxVal = max (checkVals)

    #iterate table
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor (layer,
                                [checkFld,
                                 updateFld]) as cursor:
        for check, update in cursor:
            if not check == None:
                continue

            #Calculation
            update = (check - minVal) / (maxVal - minVal)

            #update row
            row = (check, update)
            cursor.updateRow (row)

    del cursor
```

Then type `Calculation ("OD_Vil_MHNDI_albers", "Ia", "Is_")` in the python window to run the function. Make sure that between the parenthesis the first input is your layer name (from the TOC), then the field with the values to base the calculation on, then the field to update.

[image]

Assumes 10.1 +.