# Math functions in ArcMap field calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, field-calculator, python-parser

I would like to calculate the mean and the Standard Deviation as part of a script
Pre-Logic script Code:

```
 def z_score(val, mu, sigma, inc=10.0, cat=10): 
    return (0 if  val < mu else min(cat, int(abs(val-mu)/float(sigma)/float(inc)+1)))

Symbiology = z_score(!Gamma!,1520,60,1,10)
```

In place of the 1520 I want the Mean value of the gamma column, and in place of the 60 I want the STDEV. What is the correct syntax?

Comment: You would need to compute these values.  Doing it in the pre-logic script is likely to cause grief. Please [Edit] the question to specify a tag for the actual major release in use, and include the minor release in the question body.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite similar to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169265/calculating-statistics-of-attribute-field-to-use-it-in-another-calculation), and either field calculator or update cursor logic can be employed. If you insist using Field Calculator, as Vince mentioned, it may cause grief in the long run.

What I would do is as follows:

**Pre-logic script**

```
import numpy
target_field = "Gamma"
vals = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray("my_layer_in_TOC", target_field, skip_nulls=True)
mu = numpy.mean(vals[target_field])
sigma = numpy.std(vals[target_field])

def z_score(val, inc=10.0, cat=10): 
    return (0 if  val < mu else min(cat, int(abs(val-mu)/float(sigma)/float(inc)+1)))
```

And your actual field calculation becomes

**Symbiology=**

```
z_score(!Gamma!, 1, 10)
```

Please note that, `"my_layer_in_TOC"` is the layer in your map document that you are
processing and because it is a layer reference, any selection will be honoured (i.e., mean and std calculations will be based on your selection, if any).